How is the electrical information within a biological system measured using simple wires?
I would like to better understand how electrical signals within biological tissues are measured using simple wires. On one end, the exposed wire tip is embedded within biological tissue (for example, cardiac muscle tissue). On the other end, let's say that the wire is hooked up to an op-amp. For those who do not know, the cardiac muscle tissue will have oscillations in its ion concentrations local to the embedded wire tips. For example, suppose there is a 1 Hz sodium ion (Na+) concentration fluctuation that takes place near the embedded tip.
Below is a representative graphic of a bipolar electrode setup designed for differential amplification:

The exposed wire tips are embedded in the cardiac tissue, and then the insulated portion of the two wires extend over to the op-amp.
Here is my question:

How exactly is the ion concentration information of the biological tissue propagating through the wire and 'into' the op amp input terminals?

Are the electrons of the wires confined to each wire and simply being pushed towards or pulled away from the op-amp input terminals depending on the charge experienced at the tissue-embedded wire tips? Accordingly, the op-amp will see different electric fields near its input terminals depending on the concentration of the ions near the tips...and this is the underlying source of 'signal'. Perhaps my graphic below will better illustrate my description:

Or is something else happening? I know that batteries literally donate (and consume) electrons to the wires...but this seems different.
